# Decrypting PHP aes encryption in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, aes

I've been programming for years now, but never had to do anything with encryption/decryption.

So I've got the following PHP:

```
function base64_url_decode($input) {
 return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_,', '+/='));
}

function AESdecrypt($phrase, $user_key){
    $key = pack('H*', $user_key);

    $ciphertext_dec = base64_url_decode($phrase);

    # may remove 00h valued characters from end of plain text
    $plaintext_dec = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key,
                                    $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

    return $plaintext_dec;
}

echo AESdecrypt(
    "-GZmiQhJYnzw0FXTR6QoLryPNlgcScbfgZnmzgA35tydozNwsKWdXvIEtqWjhJIGCYdVVKB0lBKUTx-TXxHnIQn680mZIZ8lG7HNTMgprxM,",
    "2dd9bb29d2e25c18bdc12d7b75f6f5d0ef3d99ef310a0319e2796bb30278b24c557f78b6c958faa55d70ce081f2607a0e62b9fa01e2483f9a75b032b7fd9678c"
);
```

The output of this is

`1kYJjUajo8bIlsT5CVCSqYglD_dQX-fjuIHkEFzfJouiI7Nx29IEtZ8QwTvIH6yx5uI,`

I've created a JS fiddle to simulate what I have in javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/NdT3P/3/ (please scroll down to line 545 since I've pasted in some libraries I was using).

Relevant Javascript code:

```
var user_key = "2dd9bb29d2e25c18bdc12d7b75f6f5d0ef3d99ef310a0319e2796bb30278b24c557f78b6c958faa55d70ce081f2607a0e62b9fa01e2483f9a75b032b7fd9678c";

user_key = pack('H*', user_key);

console.log(user_key); // same as the php functions

var decrypted_wallet = "-GZmiQhJYnzw0FXTR6QoLryPNlgcScbfgZnmzgA35tydozNwsKWdXvIEtqWjhJIGCYdVVKB0lBKUTx-TXxHnIQn680mZIZ8lG7HNTMgprxM,"

decrypted_wallet = Base64.decode(strtr(decrypted_wallet, '-_,', '+/='));
console.log(decrypted_wallet); //same as the php function

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(user_key,decrypted_wallet,{ mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB });

console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)); // empty string
```

Anyone could point in the right direction?

Comment: As far as I know, MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 uses a 128 bit key, not a 512 bit one.

Comment: Well, those are just php.js functions. The last 10 lines are only relevant.

Comment: I've added the relevant javascript to my first post. The 500 lines I copied into that jsfiddle are giving the expected result. `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(user_key,decrypted_wallet,{ mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB });` is where it goes wrong

Comment: @Martijn19: Well that makes it a different picture now. If you just add some pointers - in case relevant to what you do in your question - by the name of which libraries that are, might be useful, too.

Comment: Well, I'm having trouble to convert `mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);` to javascript. My equivalent `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(user_key,decrypted_wallet,{ mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB });` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Martijn19 "Doesn't seem to work" is not a good error description. Error, completely different value, partially different value, too short, too long?